# can't get swiping to work for jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

newbie here, sorry if I don't understand all the correct ins and outs of posting...
I have visited a few pages to try to understand swiping left and right for jquery mobile. 
I visited this page for my script - http://designicu.com/jquery-mobile-swipe/
for whatever dumb reason, I can't get it to work, at all. I am sure I am missing something small and stupid...
Can anyone see my issue? thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html  lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_/css/jquery.mobile.css" />

    <script src="_/javascript/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="_/javascript/jquery.mobile.js"></script>

    <script>

    $('div.ui-page').live("swipeleft", function(){
    var nextpage = $(this).next('div[data-role="page"]');
        if (nextpage.length > 0) {
        $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, "slide", false, true);
        }
    });
    $('div.ui-page').live("swiperight", function(){
        var prevpage = $(this).prev('div[data-role="page"]');
        if (prevpage.length > 0) {
        $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {transition: "slide",
        reverse: true}, true, true);
        }
    });
    </script>

</head>

<body> 

    <div data-role="page" id="editor">
    <div>bucker</div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="innovation1">
    <div>bunk</div>
    </div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated(1.7) and removed in 1.9, use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead

Comment: I just removed my local jquery mobile script, jquery script, and jquery mobile css file, and added cdn links for each, changed .live to .on and still no dice...

Comment: which is the version of jquery used that is importatnt

Comment: the css link I am using is 1.3.0.min.css
the jquery link I am using is 1.8.2.min.js
the jquery mobile link I am using is 1.3.0.min.js
in that order also the above script in the head...
I thought both jquery and jquery mobile were important/necessary?...

Comment: check your browser console for any errors

Comment: no errors shown in log

Comment: I have had trouble with on with jQM.  Try using $(document).delegate('.ui-page','swipeleft'...etc and see if it helps.  I don't know why this should be, but it has worked for me.

Comment: Also..just to try and hone in on the source of your problem, you might try binding to ui-content instead, as that is the primary swipe area (mostly).  Also, add a console.log inside of the function body to see if it is registering your swipe event or not

Comment: thanks Arun for input
thanks 1167442 for suggestion, I will give your solution a go in the morning, is late and I am tapped and ridiculously frustrated at the moment! I finally did find another solution that worked as well. http://jsfiddle.net/GYAB7/2/ while it did work, I like the original option better if I can get it to function for me, as the fiddle solution works, but original option seems a bit more flexible. thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made you a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/NV6Py/

```
$(document).on('swipeleft', '[data-role="page"]', function(event){    
    if(event.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
    {    
        var nextpage = $(this).next('[data-role="page"]');
        // swipe using id of next page if exists
        if (nextpage.length > 0) {
            $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, {transition: "slide", reverse: false}, true, true);
        }
        event.handled = true;
    }
    return false;         
});

$(document).on('swiperight', '[data-role="page"]', function(event){   
    if(event.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
    {      
        var prevpage = $(this).prev('[data-role="page"]');
        if (prevpage.length > 0) {
            $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {transition: "slide", reverse: true}, true, true);
        }
        event.handled = true;
    }
    return false;            
});
```

And you version is working just fine. I have replaced only js and css initialization with jQuery 1.8.2 and jQuery Mobile 1.2. Here take a look:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    $('div.ui-page').live("swipeleft", function(){
    var nextpage = $(this).next('div[data-role="page"]');
        if (nextpage.length > 0) {
        $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, "slide", false, true);
        }
    });
    $('div.ui-page').live("swiperight", function(){
        var prevpage = $(this).prev('div[data-role="page"]');
        if (prevpage.length > 0) {
        $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {transition: "slide",
        reverse: true}, true, true);
        }
    });
    </script>

</head>

<body> 

    <div data-role="page" id="editor">
        <div>bucker</div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="innovation1">
        <div>bunk</div>
    </div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I too was banging my head on how can I make this work. U did it again +1

Comment: @Gajotres : How can i change url also while swiping to next page? I need to have a option to book mark all the pages. Thanks in advance

Comment: I need to append #page_name at the end of the url.